# View Dask Task Graph

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am using the Dask `submit` and `gather` paradigm to do something like:

```
data_future = client.scatter(data, broadcast=True)

futures = []
for i in range(10):
    futures.append(dask.submit(some_func, i, data_future))

results = dask_client.gather(futures)
```

Is there some way to view/visualize the DAG in this paradigm after the computation has completed?

The [documentation](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/graphviz.html) appears to be well suited for the Dask delayed paradigm. In case it matters, this is for a distributed cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2019-06-21, not really, no.

You can view it live on the dashboard's `/graph` page but there isn't any convenient code to render a static image of the graph today.  I would say that this is in scope, but not something that current maintainers are thinking very hard about today.

Comment: Thank you! This isn't a high priority item but I'm just making sure that I'm not missing something in the docs.